# Validations using AWK

Tags: bash, validation, unix, awk

```
a=1

echo -n "Enter book id: "; read book_id;
while [ $a -eq 1 ]
do
a=$(awk '{ if($3 == "$book_id") print 1; else print 0}' exercise1_data.txt)
echo $a
if [ $a -eq 1 ]; then
echo -n "Please enter unique book id: "; read book_id
fi
done
```

I am trying to check if the book id entered by the user is unique or not. What I am doing is checking in the file "exercise1_data.txt" if there is any instance of "book_id". 
The while loop is to be executed until the user inputs a unique book id.

I am getting an error `Too many arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly fixing the awk:

You need to pass shell variables to `awk` using the `-v` option:

```
awk -v b_id="$book_id" '$3==b_id{print 1;exit}END{print 0}' exercise1_data.txt
```

Also if `$3==b_id` you should `print 1` and `exit` as a match is found. Only `print 0` when we reach the end of file (no match found).

---

Secondly the script:

```
$ cat file
book_1 orielly 100
book_2 wiley 101
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1

while [ "$a" -eq 1 ]; do
    echo -n "Please enter unique book id: "
    read book_id
    let a=$(awk -v b_id="$book_id" '$3==b_id{print 1;exit}END{print 0}' file)
    echo "$a"
done
```

Demo:

```
$ bash script.sh
Please enter unique book id: 100
1
Please enter unique book id: 101 
1
Please enter unique book id: 102
0
```

Notes:

- Always quotes your shell variables.
- You are using whitespace as a field separator in the book file this won't be flexible i.e books titles, authors ect all have whitespace.

Comment: The error still persists... please could you help assemble the code.. i am new to awk programming...

Comment: That's because the error was a `bash` error not an `awk` error. I have added the correct `bash` script. Please upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the tip on the `field separator` i really hadn't thought about that.. There is something else that I was wondering. All the tutorials that I have followed showed that the awk has a syntax `awk ' BEGIN{} {} END{}'` where any combination of the three may be used. There are a few things that I see new in your code: there is no `if($3==b_id)`  and is the snippet `{print 1; exit}` a part of `if` statement or a part of `awk process segment`.

Comment: Each block `{}` in `awk` can had a conditional. Only if the conditional is true will the block be applied to that line. With no conditional and the block is applied to every line. The special `BEGIN{}` is ran before any input files are read and `END{}` is ran after all files have been read.